# htaccess throwing error on second RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/? /pages/index.php?page_url=$2&lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/? /pages/index.php?page_url=home&lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Both rules work fine on their own, but if I have them both I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

What I'm trying to do is on `site.com/en/` got to `site.com/pages/index.php?page_url=home&lang=$1` (en in this case)

but on `site.com/en/home/` go to `site.com/pages/index.php?page_url=$2&lang=$1` (home and en respectively in this case)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 500 error because your rules are looping due to wrong regex.

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /pages/index.php?page_url=$2&lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /pages/index.php?page_url=home&lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```